# How to identify make/model of a wardrobe?

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

We moved into a new flat which was sold to us with some wardrobes. We thought: "Cool! Less furniture to buy." After some time, we realised we wanted an extra shelf here, an extra hanger there, etc. Sound simple: Just go to the local furniture shop (e.g., IKEA, Jysk, Mio, whatever) and buy the furniture component you need.

Soon we realised that furniture is like phone charger plugs: Even for a simple item like a shelf, there are endless variations of width, depth, side hole placement, which makes it impossible to mix furniture components, even coming from the same make, unless they are part of the exact same system.

We could just dump all wardrobes and start anew, but that would be super-wasteful.

Is there a way to identify what make/model a wardrobe is?

Answer (score 1):

Ikea usually has very distinctive structure, and usually "Ikea" stamped somewhere.  I don't have much experience with Jysk or Mio, but as far as I remember their furniture is more of the generic type.

BUT even for Ikea this is not that simple, they don't sell single shelves and their systems tend to slightly change over time.

Hangers are simple enough, you could probably find something generic in Krauta or bauhaus. Shelves are a little more challenging but you can always use generic shelf brackets and cut a piece of wood in with same color and thickness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way, other than if it has a label, or the assembly instructions were with it.....there's a reason the instructions say to keep in a safe place....but as for shelves, as far as I am aware, shelf pins come in 2 or 3 sizes. Take one of your shelves out now, pull the holding pin out, go to your store of choice and match the pin you have to what's available. For the shelf itself, generally you buy the depth you want, in a length close to what you need, and trim the end to fit. I assume that even Ikea would use common sized shelf pins, but my closest Ikea is a 6hr drive roundtrip. But I know that Ace Hardware, BigLots, Wal-Mart, Home Depot, Lowes, K-Mart, etc, all have these self assemble cabinets, cubes, closets, wardbrobes, etc. All are made in China, or use components from China, but use standard shelf pins. Adding a shelf to one that didn't have enough was a matter of buying the extra shelf material and cutting to size. Now for the shelf, you could have variations in the thickness of the shelf. Generally, the replacement components are thicker than what ships with the original unit. Not usually a big deal unless you want uniformity, in which case you could spread the shelves so they don't look to be different thicknesses.